# Vuejs and vue-qrcode-reader add beep scan

Tags: vue.js

Hello I use the library view-qrcode-reader for QR Code scan. I try to add a BEEP scan but I do not feel that the library does this kind of thing. So I did the thing manually but it does not work either.

```
    <template>
  <div class="container" id="app">
    <router-link class="waves-effect waves-light btn" to="/livreur"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
    </router-link>
    <div class="row center">
      <span v-if="errors" class="card-panel white-text red darken-1"><strong>{{ errors }}</strong></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row infos">
      <span v-if="infos" class="card-panel white-text green green-1"><strong>Email & SMS envoyé à {{ infos.firstname }} {{ infos.lastname }}</strong></span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
      <qrcode-stream @decode="onDecode"></qrcode-stream>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  var attributes = {
    setting: {
      soundSrc: '/sounds/beep.mp3'
    }
  }
  export default {
    name: 'prepa',
    data () {
      return {
        infos: '',
        errors: '',
        success: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onDecode (decodedString) {
        var audio = new Audio(attributes.setting.soundSrc)
        audio.play()
        this.$http.get('/orders/delivery/prepa/' + decodedString, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`}})
          .then(request => this.trackingInfos(request))
          .catch((request) => this.trackingFail(request))
      },
      trackingInfos (req) {
        if (req.data.error) {
          return this.trackingFail(req)
        }
        this.errors = ''
        this.infos = req.data.datas
        this.save()
      },
      trackingFail (req) {
        if (req.data.error) {
          this.errors = req.data.error
        }
      },
      save () {
        this.$http.post('/order_histories', {
          location: this.infos.city,
          status: '/api/order_statuses/' + this.$preparation,
          User: '/api/users/' + localStorage.userId,
          orderId: '/api/orders/' + this.infos.orderId,
          headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`}
        })
          .then(request => this.successPrepa(request))
          .catch(() => this.failPrepa())
      },
      successPrepa (req) {
        if (req.data.error) {
          return this.failPrepa(req)
        }
        this.errors = ''
        this.success = req.status
      },
      failPrepa (req) {
        if (req.data.error) {
          this.errors = req.data.error
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

No beep and an error that appears in the console.

> :8080/sounds/beep.mp3:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/sounds/beep.mp3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>   :8080/#/prepa:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Thanks for your help.